# Embeds double after I execute this command

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Every time I try to use my code to test any errors it doubles the amount of embeds required. I don't put any arguments or anything after I put -ban

```
        let mention = message.mentions.members.first()
        if(!args[0]){
            message.channel.send(utils.usageEmbed("-ban @member <reason>")).then(msg => { msg.delete({timeout: 15000 })})
            message.delete({timeout: 15000})
            return
        }
        if(!mention){          
            message.channel.send(utils.usageEmbed("-ban @member <reason>")).then(msg => { msg.delete({timeout: 15000 })})
            message.delete({timeout: 15000})
            return
        }
        if(!args[1]){
            message.channel.send(utils.usageEmbed("-ban @member <reason>")).then(msg => { msg.delete({timeout: 15000 })})
            message.delete({timeout: 15000})
            return
        }
        else{
            let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")
            let member = message.guild.members.resolve(mention)
            member.ban({reason: reason})
            message.channel.send(utils.embed("GREEN", "Banned", `You have banned ${member}`))
            let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(config.mod_logs)
            channel.send(utils.embed("GREEN", "User Banned", `User: ${member}\nModerator: ${message.author}\nReason: ` + "`" + reason + "`"))
            return
        }
```

Can someone please help me? I am very confused on why this is happening. The code before was doing perfect and now it just doesn't want to work correctly. Please help! Thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it doubles the amount of embeds required"?

Comment: I mean I do the command and it does 2 embeds of the same instead of 1 embed

Comment: Maybe you have multiple shells open in VS Code

Comment: Then it is very likely that the command runs twice. Put a `console.log("running ban command")` just below the mention declaration. If you see multiple "running ban command" logs, then the command is ran multiple times. If it increases the amount of embeds sent, I suppose you have a wrongly setup listener where it creates a new message listener every time you run the ban command (or any command).